# filter for image proceccing is not aplied

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am studing someones code which remove all colors exept chosen one.
If to replace next line in code sample it will try to paint black  everything eccept red

> nonRedIndex = (hPlane > 20) & (hPlane < 340);

However, i found that other diaposons does not works. Can you tell me why?

```
cdata = imread(path);
hsvImage1 = rgb2hsv(cdata);         %# Convert the image to HSV space
hPlane = 360.*hsvImage1(:,:,1);     %# Get the hue plane scaled from 0 to 360
sPlane = hsvImage1(:,:,2);          %# Get the saturation plane
lPlane = hsvImage1(:,:,3); 
nonRedIndex = (hPlane > 140) & ...  %# Select "non-red" pixels
              (hPlane < 120);
sPlane(nonRedIndex) = 0;           %# Set the selected pixel saturations to 0
lPlane(nonRedIndex) = 0;
hsvImage1(:,:,2) = sPlane;          %# Update the saturation plane
hsvImage1(:,:,3) = lPlane;


rgbImage1 = hsv2rgb(hsvImage1);
```

Comment: I don't know if that is a typo, but you are tring to get pixels that are larger than 140 and at the same time smaller than 120. This could be a problem.

Comment: yep it was a typo, thank you) you can post it as your answaer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a wrong logical conjunction - hPlane elements have to be larger than 140 and at the same time smaller than 120. This should work:

```
nonRedIndex = (hPlane < 140) & (hPlane > 120);
```